# jQuery onmouseenter and onmouseleave firing on position/size changes animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just known that jQuery `onmouseenter`/`onmouseleave` event will also fire every time the *position/size* of element changes *during animation*, so I use a simple validation by using `if (img$.is(':animated')) return false;` in the beginning of both event handlers.

But, this causes another problem, which is sometimes the `mouseleave` event will never been executed just because of the `mouseleave` has returned false early while the `mouseenter` isn't finished yet.

```js
$(function() {

  $("img[data-alt-src]").on('mouseenter', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      var img$ = $(e.currentTarget);
      if (img$.is(':animated')) return false; // the validation
      img$.finish().animate({
        opacity: '-=1.0',
        deg: '+=90'
      }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
          img$.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
          });
        },
        complete: function() {
          img$.data('tmp-src', img$.attr('src'));
          img$.attr('src', img$.data('alt-src'));
        }
      });
      img$.animate({
        opacity: '+=1.0',
        deg: '-=90'
      }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
          img$.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
          });
        }
      });
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      var img$ = $(e.currentTarget);
      if (img$.is(':animated')) return false; // the validation
      img$.finish().animate({
        opacity: '-=1.0',
        deg: '+=90'
      }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
          img$.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
          });
        },
        complete: function() {
          img$.attr('src', img$.data('tmp-src'));
        }
      });
      img$.animate({
        opacity: '+=1.0',
        deg: '-=90'
      }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
          img$.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
          });
        }
      });
    });

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block">
    <img
      src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
      data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
      alt="">
    <img
      src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
      data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
      alt="">
    <img
      src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
      data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
      alt="">
    <img
      src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
      data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
      alt="">
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I was get stucked how to get rid of this condition?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be worked... I have added `setTimout` function to flip image source in half time of animation...

```js
$(function() {
 $("img[data-alt-src]").on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var img$ = $(e.currentTarget);
  if (img$.is(':animated')) return false; // the validation
  img$.finish().animate({
   opacity: '-=1.0',
   deg: '+=90'
  }, {
   duration: 250,
   step: function(now) {
    img$.css({
     '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
     '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
     '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
     '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
     transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
    });
   }
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
   img$.data('tmp-src', img$.attr('src'));
   img$.attr('src', img$.data('alt-src'));
   img$.data('alt-src', img$.data('tmp-src'));
  }, 125);
  img$.animate({
   opacity: '+=1.0',
   deg: '-=90'
  }, {
   duration: 250,
   step: function(now) {
    img$.css({
     '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
     '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
     '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
     '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
     transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
    });
   }
  });
   }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var img$ = $(e.currentTarget);
       if (img$.is(':animated')) return false; // the validation
       img$.finish().animate({
        opacity: '-=1.0',
        deg: '+=90'
       }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
         img$.css({
          '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
          '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
          '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
          '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
          transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
         });
        }
       });
       setTimeout(function(){
        img$.data('tmp-src', img$.attr('src'));
        img$.attr('src', img$.data('alt-src'));
        img$.data('alt-src', img$.data('tmp-src'));
       }, 125);
       img$.animate({
        opacity: '+=1.0',
        deg: '-=90'
       }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
         img$.css({
          '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
          '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
          '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
          '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
          transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
         });
        }
       });
   });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative; display: inline-block">
 <img
 src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
 data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
 alt="">
 <img
 src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
 data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
 alt="">
 <img
 src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
 data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
 alt="">
 <img
 src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
 data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
 alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But it still doesn't work as expected. If the mouse is moving cross the images quickly, the `mouseleave` of previous element is not triggered. So the images weren't flipped back.